# May I Convert Non RAC db to an RAC DB and add on a Node?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Currently my work env as 1 node none RAC database 11gR2, we are getting another machine (Linux), so I need to add on this node to our currently env and becoming a RAC db. What is the best way/route to do it? Advanced thanks!

Comment: In the documentation, there are numerous resources available online explaining how to propote a non-RAC DB to a single node Cluster (and then adding another node to the cluster).

Answer (score 1):

See the [Oracle Real Application Clusters Installation Guide 11g Release 2 for Linux and UNIX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24660/cvrt2rac.htm).  It has a section on "Converting to Oracle RAC from Single-Instance Oracle Databases" describing several different ways this can be done.

Comment: Nothing beats Oracle's thorough documentation. +1 !!!